# Training set and ARIMA plot isn't working?

Tags: r, machine-learning, time-series, training-data, arima

I'm trying to plot my training data using ARIMA with a dataset that has the dates from 2021/02/28 - 2022/03/22. But when I plot my training ARIMA, it plots 2021-2022,  leaves a  gap in the graph and starts predicting from  2027-2028 instead .

What am i doing wrong?

My code:

```
#load dataset [390 rows x 15 columns]
df = read_csv("data.csv")
#convert to time series and select the 4th column 
ts <- ts(df[1:390,4], start = c(2021, 02), end = c(2022, 03), frequency = 52)

#train data (80-20)
train <- ts(ts[1:311], start = c(2021, 02), frequency = 52)
test <- ts(ts[312:390], start = c(2021, 011),frequency = 52)

#get summary
myarima <- auto.arima(train)
summary(myarima)

#plot training ARIMA data and original dataset
fc_arima1 <- forecast(myarima, 52)
autoplot(fc_arima1)
```

my attempt: [weird arima plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWllS.png)

Answer (score 1):

Your `ts` object has 390 observations, but the last 336 are missing because you have set `end` to be part way through the data set. With frequency of 52, there are only 54 observations between the `start` of `c(2021,02)` and the `end` of `c(2022,04)`.

You should also use either the `window` or `subset` functions to form the training and test sets, so you don't have to re-specify the time series attributes.

The following should work. I've assumed your `start` date was wrong but your `end` date was correct:

```r
#convert to time series and select the 4th column 
ts <- ts(df[1:390,4], end = c(2022, 04), frequency = 52)

#train data (80-20)
train <- subset(ts, end=311)
test <- subset(ts, start=312)

#fit model
myarima <- auto.arima(train)
summary(myarima)

#plot training ARIMA data and original dataset
fc_arima1 <- forecast(myarima, 52)
autoplot(fc_arima1)
```

Comment: I'm honoured that you answered my question Rob! Big fan on your textbook. Thank you!